# How do I use VirtualBox if my processor does not support Hardware Virtualization?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, hardware-virtualization

I just checked, and my processor does not support hardware virtualization:

[image: it'soo sad :(]

Is there a way to still use VirtualBox even if my processor does not support hardware virtualization?

I was planning to run Ubuntu x86, my OS is Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you planning to run in it? Windows 8 requires Hardware Virtualization (VT) support, but older versions of 32-bit Windows should work just fine.

Comment: Hi, I was planning to run Ubuntu x86, my OS is Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Should work, no problem at all.